# Mixins and .net

Tags: c#, mixins

What are, exactly mixins?
Are there any techniques to achieve that in c#?

Comment: Wikipedia link if you're clueless like me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert, but this is what I found.

1. [Mixins in C# 3.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20120606072504/http://colinmackay.co.uk:80/blog/2008/02/24/mixins-in-c-30/)
2. [Implementing Mixins with C# Extension Methods](https://www.zorched.net/2008/01/03/implementing-mixins-with-c-extension-methods/)

***From MSDN Blog:***

> ***[Mixins In C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224093402/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2006/01/06/510034.aspx)***
>
> Some suggest that extension methods in
> the upcoming C# 3.0 are a kind of
> Mixins, because you can put in
> functionalities in these methods and
> arbitrarily tag it onto any class you
> want. In the C# 2.0 specification
> section 20.1.3 it is clearly called
> out that the base class of a generic
> class has to be a constructed class
> type so this rules out using the above
> approach to be used in C#. I am not
> too sure on why we choose to
> explicitly disallow abstract subclass.
> Since C# does not support
> multiple-inheritance, IMO it should
> have supported Mixin style coding.

Answer (score 6):

A mixin is a set of class members that can be "mixed" into a class without the problems of multi-inheritance.

C# doesn't have mixins per-se, but offers Extension Methods for similar goals.

Comment: Although is not quite a mixin. Would have a easy to see example in any pseudo or real language?

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: For example, Ruby provides the `Enumerable` mixin which can be mixed into classes that are enumerable to extend the class with methods for filtering, mapping and sorting. C#/.NET has the static `Enumerable` class which provides Extension Methods for filtering, mapping and sorting classes that are enumerable ("LINQ").

Comment: public interface IEmailItem
    {
         string SendToName { get; set; }
         string SendToAddress { get; set; }
         
    } then an extension method SendMail(this IEmailItem m){some real code here} every class implementing IEmailItem interface will "inherit" the send mail method

Answer (score 4):

Please check out [re-mix on codeplex.com](https://remix.codeplex.com/). It is an open source library to bring mixins to .NET

There you will have a step by step guide on how to implement mixins with .NET